# What is best practice to save the state of an object into a history list and restore it?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, history, snapshot, value-objects

I've got the following scenario:

I'm designing an MVVM application which communicates with some computer external devices via serial port or something. Every `Device` has some properties like an id, a name etc. and additionally consists of different `Module`'s with their own properties.
I've got a kind of xml-database to save and load devices. Each `Device` has its own file. Anyway:

The application loads all files by a kind of repository and provides a list of `Devices` to choose the one actually connected or creates a new one. When I've chosen the current `Device`, I get a page that represents a list of `Modules` based on the device's type. i.e.:

`Device_Type_A` consists of `Module_A` and `Module_B`

`Device_Type_B` consists of `Module_A` and `Module_C`

...

The properties of the `Modules` are filled via communication. Now I want to save the state of the `Modules` to a kind of module-state-history into the xml-file of the current device.

What is the best practice to do this? Is it useful to create a `ModuleSnapshot` class based on [Fowlers Snapshot](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Snapshot.html) and store it? Or do I have to do a kind of immutable value object and store it to the file?

The devices are entities but the module history entries feel like value objects. I want to show the history of a loaded device file, too. Is there a need for a `Module` class as the Model for the communication stuff and a class for an immutable value object copy of it like a `ModuleHistory`?

Something like this?

```csh
public class Device_Type_A : DeviceBase
{
    // Some special Type_A properties ...
    public string Type_A_Shape{get; set;}
    // ...       
}

public class DeviceBase
{
    public string Id  { get; private set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; private set; }
    public List<ModuleHistory> History { get; private set; }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Saving the state of object for future use.........Memento Pattern